# Display image from Bytes/bodyBytes in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, post

[image]

I'm getting an image in the HTTP POST as bytes and I want to show that in that image in flutter

Answer (score 0):

To show the image you can use `Image.memory()` it accepts `Uint8List` so you can pass your `response.bodyBytes` to show an image